# How to create columns in a csv file and insert row under them in python scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Please help me in creating columns and inserting rows under them in a csv file using python scrapy. I need to write scraped data into 3 columns. So first of all three columns are to be created and then data is to be entered in each row.

Answer (score 1):

CSV is a Comma Saparated Values format. That basically means that it is a text file with some strings separated by commas and line-downs.
Each line down creates a row and each comma creates a column in that row.

I guess the simplest way to create a CSV file would be to create a Pythonic `dict` where each key is a column and the value for each column is a list of rows where `None` stands for the obvious lack of value.
You can then fill in your dict by appending values to the requested column (thus adding a row) and then easily transform the dict into a CSV file by iterating over list indexes and for each column either add a `VALUE,` entry in the file or a `,` entry for index-out-of-bound or a None value for the corresponding list.
For each row add a line down.

Answer (score 0):

1)you can use custom Csv feed exporter each item key will be treated as a column heading and value as column value.
2) you can write a pipeline that can write data in csv file using python csv lib.